# Can't set dateformat in edit mode in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, date-format

I'm using [Matt Dotson's Real World GridView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx) in an ASP.NET 4 page, connecting to MS SQL Server 2005. Everything works as it should except for the DataFormatString property on a field with the **datetime** type - I'm trying to get just the shortdate (dd/MM/yyyy) to show up but it never changes away from long time format (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt).

Here's what I've tried:

- Setting the HtmlEncode property to False
- Removing the Culture and UICulture from my page
- Both of the above with different DataFormatStrings - {0:dd/MM/yyyy} and {0:d} (The latter because of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) document)

Any ideas what I might have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr:
Set the ApplyFormatInEditMode property to "True".

Okay, this should have been obvious - it seems the DataFormatString only applies when the row isn't in edit mode. I changed the ReadOnly property to "true" on that field and the DataFormatString was applied. Of course, this doesn't fix the problem when the users are editing a pre-existing form since all the loaded rows will be in edit mode. Then I noticed the "ApplyFormatInEditMode" property. It did exactly what it says.

This applies to normal GridViews as well, so I'll edit the title of the question.